# Custom Wp_Query still uses the main post id

Tags: wordpress

On my Wordpress website, I have the following code:

```
if ( is_page( 8 ) ) { 
    include_once('somecustompage.php');
}
```

And in my `somecustompage.php`, I use a custom `WP_Query`:

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'farewell',
    'post_status'            => 'publish',
    'pagination'             => true,
    'posts_per_page'         => '10',
    'sticky'                 => false
);

// The Query
$current_farewell_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $current_farewell_query->have_posts() ) {
    $current_farewells = '<table><tr><th>NAME</th><th>LOCATION</th><th>FAREWELL</th></tr>';
    while ( $current_farewell_query->have_posts() ) {
        $farewell_name = ( get_field('name') ? get_field('name') : '' );
        $chapels = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'chapels', array('fields' => 'name') );

        $current_farewell_query->the_post();
        $current_farewells .= '<tr>';
        $current_farewells .= '<td>' . $farewell_name . '</td>';
        $current_farewells .= '<td></td>';
        $current_farewells .= '<td></td>';
        $current_farewells .= '</tr>';
    }
    $current_farewells .= '</table>';
} else {
    $current_farewells = 'No Current Farewells.';
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

However, when I try to use the post IDs within this custom loop, both `get_the_ID()` and `$post->ID` return 8, which is the main page post id. I need to use the new post IDs that are returned in the new query.

Anybody knows how to resolve this?

Comment: Did you make sure that $args has sticky = false ?

Comment: I didn't have it, I just added it to args, but still same.

Comment: How are you looping through it?  You should post your full loop, that would help us figure it out.

Comment: @AndyWarren, I just edited the question to include the entire loop.

Answer (score 1):

I found where the problem was. Everything should've been called after this line: `$current_farewell_query->the_post();` for the query to work as expected.

Comment: I have your loop open in an editor now, I literally was just going to say your `get_the_ID()` function is happening outside the posts loop!